# Is it possible to specify an existing CloudSQL instance as the destination for the database migration service in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, database, migration, google-cloud-sql

According the GCP guides, setting up a database migration involves creating a migration job in the console using the wizard [1]. The wizard creates a new CloudSQL instance, but I would like to specify an existing instance such that we can manage the destination instance through version control (e.g. Terraform)

Is it possible to specify an existing CloudSQL instance as the destination for the database migration service in GCP? If so, how?

If not, another solution for version control is to create the migration job (and possibly the destination instance) through a script running gcloud CLI/API commands.

From the API guides for database migration [2], it seems we need to specify a **destination** connection profile.

```
destination-connection-profile-id: the destination connection profile ID
```

This is reflected in the gcloud CLI docs [3]

```
--destination=DESTINATION
ID of the connection_profile or fully qualified identifier for the connection_profile. To set the connection_profile attribute:
provide the argument --destination on the command line.
```

Does this mean that in order to create the migration job through the CLI, I will need to manually create a destination CloudSQL instance AND a connection profile for that instance as well? If so, what privileges does the connection user need? Or does the "gcloud database-migration migration-jobs create" command automatically create a destination instance?

Otherwise, open to suggestions as to what the --destination flag could mean.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/database-migration/docs/mysql/create-migration-job

[2] https://cloud.google.com/database-migration/docs/mysql/api-migration-jobs#create_a_continuous_migration_job_with_reverse_ssh_connectivity

[3] https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/database-migration/migration-jobs/create

Answer (score 2):

You asked the below questions :

- Is it possible to specify an existing CloudSQL instance as the
  destination for the database migration service in GCP?
- Does the "gcloud database-migration migration-jobs create" command
  automatically create a destination instance?
- Does this mean that to create the migration job through the CLI, I
  will need to manually create a destination CloudSQL instance AND a
  connection profile for that instance as well?
- Answer for the 1st Question : No it is not possible. My take on it is
  that Database Migration Service will always create a new instance.
  When using the wizard/Console to perform the migration service, when
  you click on create a destination it automatically creates a new
  Cloud SQL destination  instance for you. When using the API, you are
  expected to create the destination profile. See this [link](https://cloud.google.com/database-migration/docs/mysql/api-connection-profiles) where it is
  mentioned "Create a connection profile for Cloud SQL for MySQL
  destination ... The Database Migration Service for MySQL uses
  information in this request to create a new Cloud SQL for MySQL
  instance."

  I think it would be rather tricky to make the service work reliably
  if we didn't create a new instance every time. That said, I think the
  service as it exists now is designed to be able to support more
  options in the future, so it might happen, but I don't see any
  evidence that it can be done now.
- Answer for the 2nd Question : No it does not create it. When you run
  the “gcloud database-migration migration-jobs create” command, you
  have to have the source and destination connection profiles created
  and given as parameters to this command as per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/database-migration/migration-jobs/create).
- Answer for 3rd Question : No. To do this using gcloud (or the API)
  you need to create the source and destination connection profiles,
  then the migration job, and the destination instance will be created
  for you according to the information provided [here](https://cloud.google.com/database-migration/docs/mysql/api-connection-profiles#create_a_connection_profile_for_for_destination).

Your  concern with how to manage this with terraform is probably valid and perhaps interesting, but terraform is a third party product, and Google doesn't build the APIs with its model in mind. Perhaps you could create an issue with this and someone from that end can look into it.

Answer (score -1):

It is unfortunate that google chose to implement this solution in this way.
At first I thought it was more similar to the AWS approach where DMS sets up an intermediary database instance to migrate / manipulate the data before replicating to the target instance / DB engine.

Hoping they evolve this over time, but for now it does not seem like a fully complete product

Comment: Perhaps your answer should be a comment on your question. Is your post more helpful than @priyashree-bhadra answer?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/513776)